# Why aren't [String:AnyObject?] and [String:AnyObject] the same type to the swift compiler?

Tags: swift

Semantically speaking, `[String:AnyObject?]` and `[String:AnyObject]` are the same thing in terms of the way they act, meaning they will return the same thing if I access a key that wasn't set and setting a key to `nil` will remove that key from the dictionary. Why aren't they considered the same type?

EDIT: I understand the difference from the compiler point of view from the answers. I decided to put the following code in the playground:

```
var optional = [String:AnyObject?]()
var regular = [String:AnyObject]()

//Some control keys
optional["controlkey"] = "valueoptional"
regular["controlkey"] = "valueRegular"

//Set the keys
optional["keyOptional"] = "valueoptional"
regular["keyRegular"] = "valueRegular"

//Unset the keys
optional["keyOptional"] = nil
regular["keyRegular"] = nil

for (key,val) in optional {
    print("key: \(key)\tval: \(val)")
}

for (key,val) in regular {
    print("key: \(key)\tval: \(val)")
}
```

To my surprise the optional **did not** print the key that was set to nil. 
Output was as follow:

```
key: controlkey val: Optional(valueoptional) //The keys for the optional dictionary
key: controlkey val: valueRegular //The keys for the `regular` dictionary
```

**Why doesn't the key that I set to nil show up?**

Answer (score 1):

Because a nullable type and a non nullable type aren't the same thing from the compiler point of view. It just happens that the Dictionnary interface eventually "blend them" in similar entity, but this is linked with the Dictionnary implementation, not really with the type system.

EDIT: Your update changes the context of the question, but setting to nil is a way to unset from my understanding.

Comment: I asked some more!

Answer (score 1):

From the Apple docs:

> The Swift language defines the postfix ? as syntactic sugar for the
>   named type Optional, which is defined in the Swift standard
>   library.

The type AnyObject? is an enumeration with two cases, None and Some(Wrapped), which are used to represent values that may or may not be present. But AnyObject is responding to one that will be presented.

Setting nil for a key in dictionary means removing the element itself.
Try to set `NSNull()`

```
optional["keyOptional"] = NSNull()
```

Comment: I asked some more!

Answer (score 1):

They are different because you can actually store `nil` into `[String:AnyObject?]`. You cannot do it using `optional[key] = value` (subscript operator) because that one has a special behavior for `nil` (removes value) but you can do it:

```
var optional: [String:AnyObject?] = ["test": nil]
optional.updateValue(nil, forKey: "test2")

print(optional) // ["test2": nil, "test": nil]
```

Of course, getting a value from such a dictionary:

```
print(optional["test"]) // Optional(nil)
```

results in a double optional `Optional<Optional<AnyObject>>` (or `AnyObject??`) and interaction with such types is cumbersome so you should avoid storing `nil` into dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

Because setting a key to `nil` remove that key from the dictionary! From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Dictionary_Structure/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/structsub/Dictionary/s:iVs10Dictionary9subscriptFxGSqq__)

> Reading a key that is not present in self yields nil. Writing nil as the value for a given key erases that key from self

You can't store `nil` as a dictionary value. If you need something denote nothingness, use `NSNull`:

```
optional["keyOptional"] = NSNull()
regular["keyRegular"] = NSNull()
```

Comment: So at the end of the day it's an implementation decision? Interesting

Comment: That's untrue, you can store `nil` into a Swift dictionary just fine. You just cannot use subscript.

Answer (score 0):

They aren't the same type because they aren't the same type ;-) Compilers are such literal creatures.

@Sulthan's answer is correct and more complete - I didn't see it until after I hit post on my own answer. But if you look up a key in a `[String: AnyObject?]` dictionary and a value is present, you'll get an optional wrapped in an optional - the result is an `AnyObject??`. You'd have to unwrap it twice to use it:

```
var optional = [String: AnyObject?]()

// I changed it to NSString because String isn't an AnyObject
                            v
optional["controlkey"] = NSString(string: "valueoptional")

print(optional["controlkey"])    // prints "Optional(Optional(valueoptional))"
if let val = optional["controlkey"] {
    print(val)                   // prints "Optional(valueoptional)"
    if let unwrappedVal = val {
        print(unwrappedVal)      // prints "valueoptional"
    }
}
```

Comment: They don't behave the same for `nil`.